# How long does it take for Medicaid/Medicare/Private Insurance to reimburse a Health Care Facility?

Tags: surgery

How long does it normally takes Government Health Care and Private Insurance to reimburse a Health Care Facility/Hospital for a surgery?

I've heard estimates from (Incredibly Fast) 3 Months to More than year, are these numbers correct?

Comment: This depends on the insurance, the country, etc. There is no definitive answer.  Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site, particularly what kinds of questions are on topic here. Thanks!